# How to sort strings with this code? I am failing at basics

Tags: c

I am trying to sort city names inputted. The code below seems correct to me, but while it does compile successfully, it does not work as I expected.

Am I failing in understanding pointers? Let me correct if below are true:

1. `names` type is a char **
2. `names[0]` type is char *
3. If I want to swap strings after checking if they are bigger with `strcmp()`, I have to change the values inside `names[i]` and `names[j]` because the values inside these values are pointers to actual city names. When  these are interchanged, they point to each others' char array and I am done.

If my 3rd idea is true, I have to pass parameters to swap function as `char *` because swap function will take `names[i]` and `names[j]` as parameters and the type of these are char *.

The thinking was like above while writing the code below. But it seems I am failing at my logic because code does not work as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i,j;

char *temp;
void swap(char *, char *);

int main(void){

    char *names[4];
    //gets city names
    puts("Enter 4 city names:");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        names[i]=malloc(100);
        fgets(names[i],99,stdin);
    }


    //bubble sort names array and swap if necessary
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j<4 ; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp (names[i],names[j]) >0 )
            {
                swap(names[i], names[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    puts("Printing sorted array");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    getch();
}

void swap(char *first, char *second){

    temp=first;
    first=second;
    second=temp;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap function has no effect. Because I feel it is not obvious for you, let's try with a simpler example.

If you wanted to swap two integers, your function would take `int` instead of `char*`. Your function would be (I have just replaced the `char*` by `int`):

```
void swap(int first, int second){
    int temp=first;
    first=second;
    second=temp;
}
```

When you call swap(a, b) with `a` and `b` 2 `int` variables, their values are **copied** into `first` in `second`. Then you swap the contain of the variables `first` and `second`. The important point is that you **don't** change the original variables `a` and `b`.

The correct function would be:

```
void swap(int *first, int *second){
    int temp=*first;
    *first=*second;
    *second=temp;
}
```

Because that way, you pass the address of the variables and you modify the original variables this way. If it is not clear, you should document yourself about what is a pointer and how it works.

Now, you can change back the `int` by a `char*`:

```
void swap(char **first, char **second){
    char* temp=*first;
    *first=*second;
    *second=temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void swap(char **first, char **second)
{
    char *temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}
```

As it was you are only modifying the *copy* of the pointer, not the original. We use pointers to look at the original...hence you need a pointer *to a* pointer; you are modifying a pointer!!

To get your head round it, I'd recommend swapping your pointers to strings for ints and sort those instead. If it was ints you were sorting your swap function would look like this:

```
void swap(int first, int second) // These ints/parameters have been copied
{
    first = second; // This only modifies the local copy
    // etc..
}
```

To modify the original values you would need to use a pointer:

```
void swap(int *first, int *second)
{
    *first = *second;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Also Bubble Sort is basically the devil.

Comment: "You need to pass a pointer to the pointer:" Can you explain this a little bit further why? I am missing some point in this. Please

Comment: Have added some more explanation by using ints. Once you understand that you need to replace (in your thinking) "int" with "char*" hence a "pointer to a pointer" ... "pointer to a char*"

Comment: names[0] type is char*  is it true?

Comment: Correct! To make things confusing a string can be defined as an array of chars (`char MyString[100]` or as pointer `char *PointyString = "Hi"`). What you have is an array of char*: an array of strings (which you then allocate and read from the stream).

Answer (score 2):

Your swap function has no effect at all at the passed pointers, you need to change it like this, so that the passed pointers are modified:

```
 swap(&names[i], &names[j]);


 void swap(char **first, char **second)
 {
     temp=*first;
     *first=*second;
     *second=temp;
 }
```

Comment: shouldn't I change the contents of names[i] and names[j] instead of their addresses? Why adress must be passed to function? Please explain. This is the point that I dont understand.

Comment: +1, and possibly `temp` might be declared within `swap` to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap function is incorrect, you can't assign strings like that. You need something like this (non-optimal)

```
void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char tmp[256];
    strcpy(tmp, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, tmp);
}
```

Comment: This ought to work, but he wanted to swap the *pointers*. Which is not only faster but safer, if one ever changes the length or source of the strings (for this reason it would also be wiser to use `strncpy` or implement bounds checking).

Comment: @lserni i've red answer again, still don't see explicit hint than OP wanted to swap pointers rather that array contents. Surely i have to agree that most of the times your version will be faster (but depends on locality and actual sizes), and array size was hardcoded to handle this particular example. But i strongly disagree about strncpy - this function will strike you to the head while you least expecting this (ofc. i mean it will ignore \0 if size isn't enough, while it will fill remaining size with zeroes if it string is shorter - overhead!). strlcpy is far better, but nonstandard.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with pointers, but with function calls. When you pass a value to a function, and modify *that* value, the "source" of the value is not necessarily changed.

```
void swap(char **first, char **second) {
    char *temp;
    temp=*first;
    *first=*second;
    *second=temp;
}

swap(&names[i], &names[j]);
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
void swap(char **arr, int x, int y) {
    char *temp;
    temp = arr[x];
    arr[x] = arr[y];
    arr[y] = temp;
}

swap(names, i, j);
```

In the first case you pass to the function the two addresses, the contents of which are to be changed. In the second you pass the master array address, and the two locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i,j;
char *temp;

void swap(char **, char **);

int main(void){

    char *names[4];
    //gets city names
    puts("Enter 4 city names:");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        names[i]=malloc(100);
        fgets(names[i],99,stdin);
    }


    //bubble sort names array and swap if necessary
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j<4 ; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp (names[i],names[j]) >0 )
            {
                swap(&names[i], &names[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    puts("Printing sorted array");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }

}

void swap(char **first, char **second){

    temp=*first;
    *first=*second;
    *second=temp;

}
```