# why elements of structure array are not swaping ? i am trying to sort array of student structure. based on roll no

Tags: c, structure, quicksort

from main() i am calling function where record is array of struct.in swap() function i am seeing address are exchanging but in partation it is showing original address.

quick_sort(record,0,MAXNO-1);

```
void quick_sort(struct student arr[],int left,int right)
{
        int pi;
        if(left<right)
        {
                pi=partation(arr,left,right);
                quick_sort(arr,left,pi-1);
                quick_sort(arr,pi+1,right);
        }
 }
int partation(struct student str[],int low,int high)
{
        int i,j;
        struct student pivot=str[high];
        i=low-1;
        for(j=0;j<high;j++)
        {
                if(str[j].rollno < pivot.rollno)
                {
                        i++;
                        swap(&str[i],&str[j]);
                }
        }
        swap(&str[i+1],&str[j]);
        return i+1;
}
void swap(struct student *a,struct student *b)
{
        struct student *temp;
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort strings with this code? I am failing at basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912874/how-to-sort-strings-with-this-code-i-am-failing-at-basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are swapping pointers, not structures.

You can swap `struct`s in the same way you swap primitives, such as `int`s. This is how you'd swap two `int`s passed to you by pointers:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

The code for the `struct` is nearly identical:

```
void swap(struct student *a, struct student *b) {
    struct student temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're locally swapping the pointers in your `swap` method: it does nothing outside the function.

You have to dereference the pointers so it's effective, like this for instance:

```
void swap(struct student *a,struct student *b)
{
        struct student temp;
        temp=*a;
        *a=*b;
        *b=temp;
}
```